# What Is the Definition of Linear Predictive Coefficients When the Optimal Value Aren't Unique?

Tags: least-squares, lpc

Linear predictive coefficients of signal y are [defined](http://emptyloop.com/technotes/A%20tutorial%20on%20linear%20prediction%20and%20Levinson-Durbin.pdf) as the best $k$ coefficients $a_i, i = 1, \ldots, k$, that will approximate $y_n$ by $-\sum_{i=1}^k{a_iy_{n-i}}$. (Best approximation is that which minimizes the sum of squared errors.)

How are LPCs defined when this problem has multiple solutions, e.g. when y$$ is constant zero?

Comment: your example doesn't work: in case of a constant, only the first $a_1$ will be nonzero, the rest would be zero. Find a better example!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? A definition or methods to compute optimal coefficients?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, fixed it. I am asking for a definition.

Comment: In a real case I believe that it is very unlikelly that you get a full sequence of zeros. Even if this happens, it is very easy to detect this situation.

Comment: Filipe, agreed, I just did not immediately realize that full zero sequence is the only problematic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constant zero sequence is the only finite sequence for which $a_i$ are not uniquely defined.

Indeed, $a_i$ are a solution to the equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
R_0 && R_1 && \ldots && R_{k-1} \\
R_1 && R_0 && \ldots && R_{k-2} \\
\vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\
R_{k-1} && R_{k-2} && \ldots && R_0
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_k 
\end{bmatrix} = - 
\begin{bmatrix}
R_0 \\
R_1 \\
\vdots \\
R_{k-1} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To prove their uniqueness, it is sufficient to prove that the autocorrelation matrix R is nondegenerate.

If $y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_n$ is the initial sequence, $y_0 \ne 0$, and 
$$
Y = \begin{bmatrix}
y_0 && \ldots && y_n && 0 && \ldots && 0 \\
0 && y_0 && \ldots && y_n && \ldots && 0 \\
\vdots && \ddots && \ddots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\
0 && \ldots && 0 && y_0 && \ldots && y_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then 
$$
R = YY^T,
$$
so R is the Gram matrix of the rows of Y. A Gram matrix is nondegenerate iff the vectors are linearly independent, which they obviously are.

To deal with the constant zeros problem, I should probably just trim silence at the beginning and end of the audio.

Answer (score 2):

The least square solution is strictly convex. So you only have one minimum, although in cases, several combinations of inputs yield the same minimum.

Let us go back to a simpler situation: assume that you are given two numbers, $a$ and $b$, what is their best estimate? "Best" requires some more information:

- How best (distance)?
- What  do variables relates (model)?
- Where do $a$  and $b$ dwell (probability)?

If how best is a least-squares error loss function, a quadratic measure can be minimized. If the model is a polynomial function, its degree should be fixed). If $a$  and $b$  have known properties, they should be assumed.

The case of constant zero values renders most loss functions useless and reduces the space of variation to nil. In other words, if $a$ and $b$ are equal, and you don't did fancy behavior, one answer is, for  any $\alpha$,

$$ \alpha a + (1-\alpha)b$$

but you could as well:

$$  (a^\alpha b ^ \beta)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}}$$

and many others, depending on the model you wish. 
So, the proper "best estimate" is either:

- totally determined by your deterministic situation, and you ought to check input values and determine a predefined output based on logical testing (not based on stochastic optimization)
- set by "other" rules, imposed on the model ( sparse model on, $\alpha$ or $\beta$ for instance), that can give you a more "singular" solution.

So, in your case, the **simplest** model could be a solution. So what's the simplest?